# Permutation and combination/probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

1. Find the number m of 10-letter words that can be formed using the 7 letters of A and 3 letters of B.

I think for #1 it would be $$\frac{10!}{7!3!}$$

2. Among all the words, how many words begin with AAA?
3. Find the probability p that if we pick up a word then this word begins with AAA.

How would I do the other 2 problems?

Comment: You are correct for #1.  Now... for #2 note that the set of words using seven A's and three B's which start with three A's are in direct bijection with the sets of words using four A's and three B's.  E.g. $AAA\underline{BAABBAA}\mapsto BAABBAA$.  For #3, take the ratio between the two amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(2)$ and $(3)$

After choosing $AAA$, we have rest of letters arranged in $$\frac{7!}{4!3!}$$

So probability of event is

$$\frac{7!7!3!}{4!3!10!}=\frac{7}{24}$$